# Como otimizar função de calculo da entropia de shannon?

Tags: matlab

Fiz essa função para calcular a entropia de *Shannon* em um vetor de strings, esse vetor é preenchido com endereços IPs, eu gostaria de otimizar essa função já que para casos onde o vetor de entrada é muito grande, o tempo de cálculo fica muito alto.

```
function [entropy] = ShannonEntropy(IPs)
%% ENTROPY
 % Function calculates Shannon entropy for a string vector

 %% Copy vector IPs
 searchIP = IPs; 

%% Determines the size of the vector
size = length(IPs);

%% Initialize vector 
 % P will be used to calculate probability
P = zeros(size, 1);

%% Finds occurrences
for i=1:size
 for j=1:size
  if (searchIP(i) == IPs(j) && IPs(j) ~= "-1") 
   P(i) = P(i)+1;
   IPs(j) = "-1";
  end
 end
end

%% Calculate probabilities
P = P()/size;

%% Replace 0 with 1
 % ie: log 0 = NaN, log 1 = 0
P(P == 0) = 1;

%% Initialize vector
partialEntropy = zeros(size, 1);

%% Calculates entropy
for i=1:size
 partialEntropy(i) = (P(i)).*log(P(i));
end

%% Entropy sum
entropy = -sum(partialEntropy);
```

Comment: Oi as perguntas devem ser feitas em Português (por favor edite sua pergunta), e você está querendo calcular a entropia de cada coluna ?

Comment: Isso eu quero calcular a entropia de cada coluna

Comment: Sem a amostragem de uso de cada ip não dá para aplicar a fómula de Hartley I(U)= logᵦ r, que vai determinar a probabilidade de cada resultado.

Comment: para calcular somente entropia vc não precisa de mais nada do que os dados de cada coluna ... se você também precisa aplicar Hartley ai sim vc vai precisar saber a taxa de amostragem ...